# Get reference to arbitrarily (deep) nested node inside JSON/JS object using value of key

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, recursion, tree

I have been looking all night on SO with lots of similar issues but none that directly solves my problem at the moment. So please have a look below.

I have an object of the form:

```
let data = [{
   "id": 777,
   "name": "Level 1_section_1",
   "children": [{
       "id": 778,
       "name": "Level 2a",
       "children": [

       ]
     },
     {
       "id": 783,
       "name": "Level 2b",
       "children": [

       ]
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": 786,
   "name": "Level 1_section_2",
   "children": [{
     "id": 781,
     "name": "Level 2c",
     "children": [

     ]
   }]
 }
]
```

Basically, children contains an array of the same structure nodes.

If I wish to get a reference to the node that contains, say, `id:783`, I would intuitively use recursion but I'm at a loss as to how I would ensure that it covers the entire tree recursively until it finds and returns the exact node that I want so that I could append more children to the found node.

Admittedly, despite coming from a CS background, my knowledge of recursion is rather rusty.

This is what I've tried in my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hanktrizz/surmf7dq/4/

Note that the `data` tree could be arbitrarily deep (though I don't expect it to go past 8 or 9 levels of depth) but just thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using a `for` loop in a recursive function:

```js
let data=[{id:777,name:"Level 1_section_1",children:[{id:778,name:"Level 2a",children:[]},{id:783,name:"Level 2b",children:[]}]},{id:786,name:"Level 1_section_2",children:[{id:781,name:"Level 2c",children:[]}]}];

const findNode = (arr, idToFind) => {
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (item.id === idToFind) {
      return item;
    }
    const possibleResult = findNode(item.children, idToFind);
    if (possibleResult) {
      return possibleResult;
    }
  }
};

console.log(findNode(data, 778));
```

Comment: I honestly can't thank you enough for your prompt and working response. Working towards a deadline and things just weren't flowing for me. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a higher-order `findNode` that is not limited to searching by `id` alone. Instead, it accepts a user-defined lambda to search nodes using any condition -

```
findNode (n => n.id === 778, data)
// { id: 778, name: "Level 2a" }

findNode (n => n.name === "Level 2c", data)
// { id: 781, name: "Level 2c" }

findNode (n => n.id === 999, data)
// undefined
```

Verify the results in your own browser below -

```js
const data =
    [{id:777,name:"Level 1_section_1",children:[{id:778,name:"Level 2a",children:[]},{id:783,name:"Level 2b",children:[]}]},{id:786,name:"Level 1_section_2",children:[{id:781,name:"Level 2c",children:[]}]}];

const None =
  Symbol ()

// findNode : (node -> boolean, node array) -> node?
const findNode = (f, [ node = None, ...nodes ]) =>
  node === None
    ? undefined
    : find1 (f, node) || findNode (f, nodes)

// find1 : (node -> boolean, node) -> node?
const find1 = (f, node = {}) =>
  f (node) === true
    ? node
    : findNode (f, node.children)

console.log (findNode (n => n.id === 778, data))
// { id: 778, name: "Level 2a" }

console.log (findNode (n => n.name === "Level 2c", data))
// { id: 781, name: "Level 2c" }

console.log (findNode (n => n.id === 999, data))
// undefined
```

Above, destructing assignment permits an elegant expression but also creates unnecessary intermediate values. The following revision is a significant improvement -

```js
// findNode : (node -> boolean, node array, int) -> node?
const findNode = (f, nodes = [], i = 0) =>
  i >= nodes.length
    ? undefined
    : find1 (f, nodes[i]) || findNode (f, nodes, i + 1)

// find1 : (node -> boolean, node) -> node?
const find1 = (f, node = {}) =>
  f (node) === true
    ? node
    : findNode (f, node.children)
```

Both version offer short-circuit evaluation and will stop iteration immediately after the first result is found

Comment: I like the idea of the predicate. I incorporated it as well.

Comment: Nice as always!  I wonder if `find1` might be better declared as `(f, node, { children = [] } = node) => ...`.  This would let the predicate test the existence of or contents of `children` and would return a reference to the actual node in the tree rather than a partial clone.  (Or perhaps more simply, `(f, node) => ... : findNode(f, node.children)`.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The simplified version is probably better for this specific answer since the input nodes all appear to have a well-defined `children` property

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here's one that attempts to return all instances.

```js
var data=[{id:777,name:"Level 1_section_1",children:[{id:778,name:"Level 2a",children:[]},{id:786,name:"Level 2b",children:[]}]},{id:786,name:"Level 1_section_2",children:[{id:781,name:"Level 2c",children:[]}]}]

var f = (o, pred, acc=[]) =>
  pred(o) ? [o] : Object.values(o).reduce((a, b) =>
    b && typeof b == 'object' ? a.concat(f(b, pred, acc)) : a, acc)

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(data, o => o.id == 781)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(data, o => o.id == 786)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

Main advantage is that you get access to other data in `filterFn` and can easily do further processing. Obviously there is a trade-off in introducing a dependency

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = [{ id: 777, name: 'Level 1_section_1', children: [{ id: 778, name: 'Level 2a', children: [] }, { id: 783, name: 'Level 2b', children: [] }] }, { id: 786, name: 'Level 1_section_2', children: [{ id: 781, name: 'Level 2c', children: [] }] }];

const treeSearch = (data, id) => objectScan(['**(^children$)'], {
  useArraySelector: false,
  abort: true,
  rtn: 'value',
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value.id === id
})(data);

console.log(treeSearch(myData, 778));
// => { id: 778, name: 'Level 2a', children: [] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.7.1"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)